# How does 'input data' get stored?

Tags: vue.js

Simple question/concept I am trying to grasp, thank you in advance for your help, this community has been a huge tool for me.

Okay so... using this example, below (click the link for video), how do I go about storing the 'likes' hypothetically.

[image]

[Video](https://www.useloom.com/share/e8342acd84e440e283f1ababd758eb0b)

Would this be done in a DB? (which would you recommend, I have used MongoDB and have been playing around with google firestore)

How does the data get sent? Is this related to 'state management' in Vue? Is this where tools like nuxt.js and vuex come in handy? (Do these questions even make sense? )

Cheers

Comment: You are not specifying what you are trying to build, what are your limitations/requirements, etc. Seems like you're asking for general education on web page building, not on VUE (and that's the sole tag you have). Try reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to handle a *rating* or *like* system is an **opinionated** answer.

You could do your business logic in the backend (like you proposed to do with MongoDB or Firebase) and create your front-end using Nuxt.js. With Vuex you get a centralized state management for your HTTP Request proccess, keeping it easy to maintain.

Check out [Vuex examples](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples), they are highly valuable.